# constructor of a controller don't take a param mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, constructor, nullreferenceexception

why when i add a param for the constructor of the controller, I get an error.

this is my code:

```
public partial class RegistrationController : Controller
    {

        public RegistrationController(int i)
        {


            }
 public ActionResult Index()
    {}

}
the error is `Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:


Line 14: 
Line 15:     <fieldset>
Line 16:         @{string visibleCountry = (Model.CountryParam == ConfigurationParamValue.NotVisible) ? "display:none" : "display:inline";
Line 17:           string mandatoryCountry = (Model.CountryParam == ConfigurationParamValue.isMandatory) ? "display:inline" : "display:none";  
Line 18:           <div id="county" style="@visibleCountry">


Source File: e:\VP5-Nuguet\src\Registration\Registration.Front.Web\Views\Registration\Index.cshtml    Line: 16

Stack Trace:


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Registration_Index_cshtml.Execute() in e:\VP5-Nuguet\src\Registration\Registration.Front.Web\Views\Registration\Index.cshtml:16
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9630364
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929 `
```

Comment: what is the point of the parameter?

Comment: also add a default constructor with no parameter

Comment: Also, read up on routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist the the constructor parameter you have to build your own ControllerFactory implementing the `IControllerFactory` interface and set it in the app start.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC will try to instantiate the controller specified in the route for each request by calling its default constructor.

From the looks of it, you want to hit a URL like: `/registration/{someNumber}`.

If this is the case, move the `int id` from the constructor to the action method:

```
public partial class RegistrationController : Controller
{
        public RegistrationController()
        { }

        public ActionResult Index(int i)
        { 
          // do something
        }
}
```